# How to return object type and ID?

Tags: rest-api

How i will return the rest response with object type and contactID to the end user in json format. When compile this code it through error.

> "Compile Error: Invalid type: String at line 5 column 16"

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/1.0/Persons/*')

global class SQUser

{

 @HttpGet

 global static string CheckLead()

 {

   String EmailID = RestContext.request.params.get('Email_id');
   LIST<Contact> conID = [Select ID from Contact where Email=:EmailID LIMIT 1];
   LIST<Lead> ledID = [Select ID from Lead where Email=:EmailID LIMIT 1];
   if(conID.size()>0)
   {
     return  Schema.Contact.ID.getDescribe().getType()+conID[0].ID;
     //return 'ContactID '+ conID[0].ID;
   } 

}
```

Comment: Can you clarify which line in the source the error corresponds to? Also, `Schema.Contact.ID.getDescribe().getType()+conID[0].ID;` probably won't compile as you are concatenating a DisplayType with an Id. Did you want to get something out of the DisplayType?

Comment: It would be worth updating the title of the question to make it clearer that you are looking for a JSON string to be returned e.g. `How to return object type and ID as a JSON string?`

Answer (score 2):

The List class has the getSObjectType method. So did you mean this:

```
return conID.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName() + conID[0].Id;
```